# Getting user generated content with no titles to rank

Tags: seo, title, user-generated-content

We are creating a site that allows users to generate content. The user is provided with a text field only (no title), similar to Twitter, Facebook, and Google+. Each piece of content created by the users will have a dedicated page/URL.

Since the page has no title, I was wondering how search engines will index and display our pages. If the content was shared on other social networks, what will those results look like if there is no title for the open graph or Twitter tags?

Answer (score 1):

Google can index pages with no title page.  When there is no title tag, they will choose a snippet to use as the title.

Google does [recommend using a title tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624) as an SEO signal that will help your site rank.  It might be better to choose your own snippet from the post.  3 to 7 words with the author name and the site name in the title is probably going to be better than what Google comes up with.

I have never tested trying to share content with no titles on social networks.  My guess is that, like Google, they can do it, but it won't look as good as if there were a title.

Taking a step back, why would each short post need its own full page?  Even if searchers do land on your page, I doubt they will have a good user experience.     Landing pages need enough content to satisfy the user.  That is usually a lot more than just a sentence or two.  You should think about using this content to build pages with multiple posts on each page rather than a single page for each post.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  As for generating a title, how could this be done if its user generated content? Any moderators won't be helping generate titles.

As to your last remark, I would agree with you that seeing a short post on a page is not a great experience. However, the post's page is a fallback from search engines (and it will be filled with other content).  When the user is viewing all posts on the feed page, a single post would be opened via a modal so users can see larger images and comments.  Would you suggest a different architecture?

Comment: You can get a snippet out of the post yourself.  Then fill it in with some additional information like the user name and the site name.